# Can recordset values be used as Excel index values?

Tags: vba, excel

I have Excel spreadsheet that gets its settings from an Oracle database. I'm trying to update each worksheet's row height by calling the worksheet using a recordset value (the name of the worksheet). rsSettings(1) is a string value that's the worksheet name. rsSettings(2) is a row number and rsSettings(3) is a row height. This is giving me a Type Mismatch error:

```
Do Until rsSettings.EOF
    WB.Worksheets(rsSettings(1)).Cells(rsSettings(2), 1).RowHeight = rsSettings(3)
    rsSettings.MoveNext
Loop
```

This does work if I replace rsSettings(1) with a literal string value or a string variable that gets its value from rsSettings(1) or (as I just found out) if I do CStr(rsSettings(1)). (And also, I can write the value to a cell.)

So while the problem is solved for now using CStr(), should it be possible to use a recordset value as a string value where an index value would go?

Comment: Try `CDbl(rsSettings(3))` to coerce that to a `Double` precision numeric value.

Comment: Try specifically using the `.Value` property of the field instead of relying on the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .Value works for strings. Thanks!